# Create DOUBLE PRECISION column from VARCHAR that is 99% numbers... (but includes some strings)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use Postgresql. I have a varchar column RAW_RET, mostly of numbers, and I'm trying to make a new column RET which is DOUBLE PRECISION. The problem is that a few rows of RAW_RET contain text, (Eg. character `'B'` instead of numbers. Hence the following command:

```
update q_stock.daily set RET = cast(RAW_RET as double precision) ;
```

returns an error, `invalid input syntax for type double precision: "B"`

It seems like I need to do something like select only numeric rows, but I'm struggling at the moment to figure out how to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real numbers, you can use a regular expression:

```
update q_stock.daily
    set RET = cast(RAW_RET as double precision) 
    where RAW_RET ~ '^[-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$';
```

Comment: Perfect! This seemed like a simple REGEX problem but I'm still learning SQL.

Comment: A small update to the regex might be `'^-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$';` though on my dataset, it doesn't matter

Comment: @MatthewGunn . . . I made those changes.  And fixed the intro sentence.